# Azure Mobile Service Facebook Authentication android client fails

Tags: android, facebook-login, azure-mobile-services

I am creating an android app which uses Azure mobile services. I managed to connect to my azure mobile service and retrieve data.

Then I wanted to include Facebook authentication in to my app.

```
MobileServiceClient class has a method to use for authentication using Google,
Facebook, Twitter and Microsoft Live login providers.
```

Right after I inserted the following code snippet to my onCreate() method I started getting errors.

```
mClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook,
            new UserAuthenticationCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(MobileServiceUser user,
                        Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    if (exception != null) {

                        Log.d("ShopiN", "login success");
                    }

                }
            });
```

Log cat shows following.

```
04-19 08:42:18.566: D/gralloc_goldfish(3309): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-19 08:44:06.648: D/dalvikvm(3353): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 137K, 12% free 2747K/3116K, paused 143ms, total 145ms
04-19 08:44:06.748: I/dalvikvm-heap(3353): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.978MB for 1127532-byte allocation
04-19 08:44:06.908: D/dalvikvm(3353): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 9% free 3846K/4220K, paused 155ms, total 155ms
04-19 08:44:07.338: D/AndroidRuntime(3353): Shutting down VM
04-19 08:44:07.338: W/dalvikvm(3353): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f03648)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shopindev2/com.example.shopindev2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.LoginManager.showLoginUI(LoginManager.java:282)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.LoginManager.authenticate(LoginManager.java:143)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient.login(MobileServiceClient.java:230)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient.login(MobileServiceClient.java:214)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.example.shopindev2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-19 08:44:07.438: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     ... 11 more
```

My MainActivity class is as follows

```
package com.example.shopindev2;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceUser;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ServiceFilterResponse;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.UserAuthenticationCallback;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MobileServiceClient mClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "myServiceUrl",
                    "myAppKey", getApplicationContext());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook,
                new UserAuthenticationCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(MobileServiceUser user,
                            Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                        if (exception != null) {

                            Log.d("ShopiN", "login success");
                        }else{

                            Log.d("ShopiN", "login Failed");
                        }

                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My Android Manifest is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shopindev2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.shopindev2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am stuck here. Can anyone show me where am I missing it?

Comment: Can you tell us the service name? Like service URL?

Comment: https://shopin.azure-mobile.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that the login is working via browser. To do so, go to the following link in your browser:

```
https://<ServiceName>.azure-mobile.net/login/facebook
```

Once, you have made sure that it is working, you know that the problem is on the SDK side. To debug that problem, simply try to print the exception in `else` block or observe it by setting breakpoints.

This should give you an idea. Comment back and tell us how it goes.

Edit: Looks like you are passing an instance of `Application` to your SDK while creating `mClient` instance. You're doing the following:

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "myServiceUrl",
                "myAppKey", getApplicationContext());
```

Instead, change it to this:

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "myServiceUrl",
                "myAppKey", this);
```

This way, you are actually passing an instance of `Activity`. Mobile services would otherwise work well with the `ApplicationContext`. However, when authentication is added, the SDK needs to create a UI overlay for login. Creating UI without host activity isn't possible. That's why, the SDK requires `Activity` instance to create the login screen when authentication is added.

Comment: Hi akshay2000
Thank you for the quick reply.

Login via browser works.

But app stops before it executes the onCompleted method.

Comment: What do you mean 'app stops'? Whole login is executed on a background thread. It takes a while to receive callback. The call to `onCompleted` will be made a minute after `onCreate` method is returned. Keep an eye on threads in eclipse. You should be able to see a new thread pop up when `login` is called.
Meanwhile, I got this error on Facebook login in browser: `App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.`

Comment: App totally crashes. Please refer my Log provided above.

Comment: I followed the steps given in     http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-facebook-authentication/

Comment: @RumeshEranga Hold on a second! I know exact problem with your code. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: My Facebook app is still on Development mode. May be that's why you get that error.

Comment: Thanks akshay2000. Your fix worked perfectly. But I wonder why     getApplicationContext() works for creating the MobileServiceClient but not the Facebook authentication.

Comment: @RumeshEranga See the edited answer. It should clear things up.

Comment: That clears up everything. Thanks a lot for your help.